# Portable generation of a new file name in a specified directory

Tags: c++

How can I **portably** (I am mostly interested in windows and linux) generate a new file name in a specified directory, with specified filename prefix and suffix?

```
std::string UniqueName(std::string const& dir, std::string const& prefix,
                       std::string const& suffix);
```

Any suggestions to implement this function, with as little as possible explicit dependencies on specific platforms.

Comment: What platform/OS? There is no pure C++ way of achieving this.

Comment: What does "unique" mean?  Unique to your program?  Unique in a given directory?  Unique on a given computer?

Comment: Use the timestamp, when the file is to be created.

Comment: What do you mean by 'portable'? So you can port it to different OS's?

Comment: I don't think there's a really portable way of doing this. If you just need a temporary name without caring about the location of the file, and want to be more portable, perhaps stdio's [tmpnam](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpnam/) might be worth looking it.

Comment: You cannot generate a unique *filename* on a multitasking operating system unless you make it sufficiently random.  Creating a unique *file* shouldn't be a problem, your OS should support it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Be aware that doing this wrong is a security hole. There are tricks to exploit temporary(ish) files, and these can give Administrator access to the whole system, not just your app. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/TemporaryFileSecurity.aspx) for some advice.

A couple of ways to do this:

- Whenever possible, use library-provided functions instead of writing your own. For example, in Windows use [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991.aspx), on Linux use [`mkstemp`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html).
- Use [`boost::filesystem::unique_path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#unique_path), which lets you reliably generate unique filenames according to a template you provide.

`boost::filesystem` is scheduled to become a part of C++ TR2, which should be supported by almost all compilers in the future. Note that you must `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3` ([info](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm)), otherwise you’ll get an older version of `boost::filesystem` that doesn’t support `unique_path`.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate a UUID to create unique names. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Implementations) for a list of implementations in C++.

Answer (score 1):

For a windows solution, [Generate a guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568%28VS.85%29.aspx) and use it as the filename

Here is the code to generate the guid to get you started.

```
_TUCHAR *guidStr = 0x00;
GUID *pguid = 0x00;
pguid = new GUID;
CoCreateGuid(pguid);
// Convert the GUID to a string
UuidToString(pguid, &guidStr);
delete pguid;
```

Comment: Why use `0x00` instead of `0`? That's rather unorthodox. And just create `pguid` without automatic allocation, not dynamic allocation. At the least, use `auto_ptr`.

Comment: @GMan This is just a block of code I used for some R&D coding (Ripoff and deploy). I really haven't dug in to c++ for years. Feel free to edit my post to make it more correct for the modern coding standards.

Comment: If you're after a Windows-specific solution, you might prefer to use [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The function, given the signature you have, is impossible to implement perfectly. With filesystems, you very often have the problem of race conditions:

- Your functions decides on a filename "foobar"
- Someone else creates the file "foobar"
- Your program can't open "foobar" because someone else in step 2 beat you to it.

POSIX machines have a function to get around this: [`mkstemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp). Unfortunately, there is no Windows equivalent to this. On Windows, use [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364991.aspx), which is closer to [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktemp), but use `CREATE_NEW` when calling [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx), which will cause [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx) to fail if the file exists. From there, you can implement a Windows version of [`mkstemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp).

Answer (score 0):

untested code, but i use something very similar in a couple projects

```
std::string UniqueName(std::string const& dir = _T(""), std::string const& prefix = _T(""), std::string const& suffix = _T(""))
{
    std::string retVal = _T("");

    std::string sDirectory = boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path().string();

    if ( ! dir.empty() )
        sDirectory = dir;

    std::string sFilesName = _T("%%%%-%%%%-%%%%-%%%%");

    if ( ! prefix.empty() )
        sFilesName = prefix;

    boost::format fmter( _T("%s%s%s") );
    std::string sModel = boost::str ( boost::format ( fmter 
        % sDirectory
        % sFilesName
        % suffix ) );

    boost::filesystem::path temp = boost::filesystem::unique_path(sModel);
    retVal = temp.string();

    return retVal;
}
```